# Simple twitter timeline iOS (only read tweets for no register user)

Tags: ios, twitter

I want a twitter timeline to be displayed in a View, without the user having to put your twitter account, simplemete read the tweets and hashtag, of the accounts that I have selected during the programming of the app. 
Is it possible? Where do I can find info for this? 
All I see includes login in twitter.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use STTwitterAPIWrapper

Firstly using Twitter you must create an app , because you must use key and secret of your app in the code.

For example :

```
STTwitterAPIWrapper *twitter = [STTwitterAPIWrapper twitterAPIApplicationOnlyWithConsumerKey:YourTwitterConsumerKey
                                  consumerSecret:YourTwitterConsumerSecret];

    [twitter verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock:^(NSString *username) 
    {

        NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"q" : @"anyHashTag", @"result_type": @"recent", @"count": @"100"};

        [twitter getSearchTweetsWithQuery:parameters successBlock:^(NSDictionary *searchMetadata, NSArray *statuses, NSString *refreshUrl) {

            _refreshUrl = refreshUrl;
            [self parseJSONString:statuses];


        } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {

            //NSLog(@"-- error: %@", error);
        }];


    } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        //NSLog(@"--** error %@", error);
    }];
```

Comment: Ummm. Thanks. But, can you be more specific? I starting on iOS... :(

Comment: Ok, I suggest you this tutorial.
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone-sdk-connect-to-twitter-with-oauth--mobile-2829